# Custom Web Part to get all Reminders for SPUser from Project server

Tags: list, site-collection, project-server

It's been tough finding good material on Project Server/SharePoint integration from a development standpoint.

What I'd like to do is create a web part that can be deployed to any sharepoint site, that gets all reminders (Tasks, timelines, timecards, issues, risks etc...) for a given SPUser.

It seems to me I need to be able to do the following:

1. Find Project Server Site in current Farm/Site Collection
2. Find all List Items where AssignedTo = SPUser
3. Returns this collection for sorting, rendering etc...

I've seen a couple walkthroughs that demand you have a Project Server Web Part on the page to get that information, and I need to be able to do this without that dependency. Where do I start?

Can I do something like:

```
var rootSiteCol =SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url
var ProjectSite = rootSiteCol.AllSitesAndWeb["Project"];
var Lists = ProjectSite.AllLists;
foreach(List in Lists)
{
    //Enumerate and win!!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found an answer, but don't want to mark the incorrect answer

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using caml to query all lists in sites and subsites?

```
<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" LookupId="TRUE"/><Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value></Eq><Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups"><FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/></Membership></Or></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="DueDate"/></OrderBy>
```

or

you can use this ;) :

http://sanjayapdl.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/single-web-part-to-display-tasks-assigned-to-current-user-and-current-users-groups/

hope it helps :)

Comment: That looks like it's specific to SharePoint standard tasks, not Project Server tasks. It IS helpful, though. Upvote for you!